# Model in MVC not being assigned values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting the error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when attempting to assign a value to a model's fields in my MVC project. My model (not strongly typed) is referenced in my view thus:

```
...Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Project.Models.MyModel>" %>
```

Intellisense picks up MyModel's fields when I access it in the view.  My model is posted below:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public int AddressTypeId { get; set; }
       ....
    }
}
```

As you can see, I do a get set on each field and everything is public.  But when I debug it, as soon as I hit anything to do with the Model, the compiler complains that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What's missing here?

Comment: How are you passing model to the view? Can you show this part of code?

Comment: How are you instantiating the model, and show the line where you get the error

Comment: Have you ever instantiated your model?

Comment: Your model is defined in `Project.Models` yet the model reference has `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RSPWebApp.Models.MyModel>`. The namespace does not match. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: "My model (not strongly typed) is referenced in my view" Wait what?

Comment: No, it's not actually called 'Project.Models' I just edited it so that it doesn't look too much like our working code.  It was because I didn't pass an instance of a model from the controller back to the view as other comments alluded to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have passed a model to this view from the controller action that rendered it:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    MyModel model = ... fetch your model from somewhere 
    return View(model); // <!-- Notice how the model must be passed to the view
}
```

Obviously the function that is retrieving your model from wherever you are retrieving it must ensure that the model is not null. Alternatively you could test in the view if the model is not null before accessing it's properties and if it is null render some alternative content.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to initialize your model first

for eg:

```
    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel(); 
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: How is your answer different from the one posted 15 minutes earlier?